# Label with background image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I try to set an image behind a Label. I use at the moment following code:

```
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

But the image doesn't fit the label complete. Pays attention to the corners. It should be round.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first make the background image stressable, then set it as the background image of the label.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:

```
UIImage *bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] 
             resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero
                            resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:bgImage];
```